# Remove "GET" from displaying in Console - WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, console

I have a WordPress site and when I inspect in the console tab of my browser I have so many "GET" lines with all the assets to my website. How can I hide those or not have them displaying?

Comment: There's probably some setting to display what type of requests in your console. For me, normally only failure of request show up though.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make as many requests?

There is no way to hide HTTP requests from the network inspector.